# Mapping .yaml file and .txt file using Id

Tags: python, text, mapping, yaml

I am new in python. Can anyone tell me how to map .yaml file and .txt file using a common Id.

settings.yaml

```
folders:
    input: /home/developer/xovis/alhokair_data/incoming   
    csv: /home/developer/alhokair_xovis/client_31_csv
    backup: /home/developer/xovis/alhokair_data/backup

client_id: 31

logging:
    log_file: /tmp/j2clog_31.log

sensors:
    -
        serial_number: "D8:80:39:D3:C6:3C"
        storecode: 105943
        chain_id: 1
        chain_name: Al Hokair
        site_id: 1
        site_name: Aldo
        zone_id: 2
        zone_name: Entrance - 2
```

Stores.txt

```
STORE,TRAN_DATE,TRAN_TIME,SALE_AMOUNT,TRAN_COUNT
105943,20170719,090000,88.00,1
105943,20170719,100000,1060.00,6
105943,20170719,120000,498.00,2
```

Map this 2 file using Storecode from YAML and Store from .txt file

Final output is like

```
STORE,TRAN_DATE,TRAN_TIME,SALE_AMOUNT,TRAN_COUNT,chain_id,chain_name,site_id,site_name,zone_id,zone_name
105943,20170719,090000,88.00,1,1,1,1,1,2,2
105943,20170719,100000,1060.00,6,1,1,1,1,2,2
105943,20170719,120000,498.00,2,1,1,1,1,2,2
```

Comment: Where is your program? What is not working in that program? What error do you get, cq. what erroneous output do you get? Please update your question with all of the above information, without it we cannot help you indicate where your program goes wrong.

Comment: I am not yet created the program.I just need help to start.

Comment: There is no standard support for YAML in Python so you have to install e.g. `ruamel.yaml` to read YAML 1.2 files (`pip install ruamel.yaml`), for reading and writing CSV use the built-in `csv` package. Start by launching your editor of choice and typing your program, once you get stuck come back here with a question appropriate for [so]

Answer (score 0):

Parsing settings files that involve yaml is dead easy.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> with open('settings.yaml') as settings_file:
...     settings = yaml.load(settings_file)
...     
>>> settings.keys()
dict_keys(['folders', 'logging', 'client_id', 'sensors'])
```

In this case you get a dictionary, and you're interested on in `sensors`. It's a list; choose the first item.

```
>>> settings['sensors'][0]
{'zone_id': 2, 'serial_number': 'D8:80:39:D3:C6:3C', 'zone_name': 'Entrance - 2', 'site_id': 1, 'chain_name': 'Al Hokair', 'chain_id': 1, 'storecode': 105943, 'site_name': 'Aldo'}
```

Define the names of the items you want from the dictionary, then select those items.

```
>>> new_items = ['chain_id', 'chain_name','site_id','site_name','zone_id','zone_name']
>>> new_values = ','.join([str(settings['sensors'][0][_]) for _ in new_items])
```

Now spin through the input file, adding the names to the first line, values to the second and subsequent lines.

```
>>> with open('stores.txt') as stores:
...     line = stores.readline().strip()
...     print (line+','+''.join(new_items))
...     while True:
...         line = stores.readline().strip()
...         if not line:
...             break
...         print (line+','+new_values)
...         
STORE,TRAN_DATE,TRAN_TIME,SALE_AMOUNT,TRAN_COUNT,chain_idchain_namesite_idsite_namezone_idzone_name
105943,20170719,090000,88.00,1,1,Al Hokair,1,Aldo,2,Entrance - 2
105943,20170719,100000,1060.00,6,1,Al Hokair,1,Aldo,2,Entrance - 2
105943,20170719,120000,498.00,2,1,Al Hokair,1,Aldo,2,Entrance - 2
```

Notice that the output is not precisely what you claimed in your question.